# javascript FB.login on Safari

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using FB.login (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/).

```
FB.init({
    appId:<id>,
    cookie: true,
    status:true,
    xfbml: true
});
FB.api("/me", function(user) {
    if (user==null || user.id==undefined) {
        $('#left-menu .facebook-login').show();
    } else {
        THIS.user = user;
        $('#left-menu .facebook-loggedin').show();
    }
});

$('#left-menu .fblogin').click(function(){
    FB.login(function(resp) { 
        if (resp.session) window.location.reload(); 
    });
});
```

This code works perfectly in Firefox and in IE8. When the user logs in, the user object is picked up after a reload. However, it does not work in Safari 5.

In Safari, after login and reload, when I do a debug inside the FB.api(...) code, the user object says

message: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
type: "OAuthException".

When I try to hit the login button again, the debug console says "FB.login() called when user is already connected."

This code is purely *client-side*. There's no server-side involvement with this login code.

Any workaround?

===================

Solved. When "xfbml: true" was removed, it worked on Safari... Don't ask me why.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. My login code is purely client-side. There's no serverside involvement at all.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you forgot to specify the XFBML namespace on your  element?

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

This is required in order to be able to parse XFBML tags.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a race condition where FB is being called before the init process is complete.  Check out https://github.com/xocialhost/jquery.xocialCore.js/blob/master/jquery.xocialCore.js for a jquery example that init's and then starts it's FB calls after it's initialized.  Look around line 71 for the start of where you could put your inline FB calls.

Additionally you'll want to use FB.getLoginStatus to check the login state instead of FB.api.

See this post: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/